# Mocking database within WCF Service

Tags: c#, database, wcf, unit-testing, mocking

I have a WCF Service where I manipulate database tables. How do I pass some argument for
the service to use the `MockDatabase` for testing purposes instead of the production `Database`.

IDatabase interface within the service:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    void addNewProduct(Product product);
}
```

MockDatabase implementing IDatabase:

```
public class MockDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public void addNewProduct(Product product)
    {
        //some impl
    }
}
```

Client getting instance of service:

```
AuthenticationClient authorise = new AuthenticationClient();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an interface for all my database operations, `IDatabase`, and created a `Database` class implementing `IDatabase`.

I then created a `DatabaseMock` class which also implemented `IDatabase`, but with altered
method bodies of which should be run during the tests.

Using `Unity` and `Moq` I was able to configure the `web.config` of the main project and the `app.config` of the test project to resolve the bindings at run time:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly  name="Ecommerce_WCF"/>
    <assembly  name="Ecommerce_WCF_Test"/>

    <alias alias="IDatabase" type="Ecommerce_WCF.IDatabase, Ecommerce_WCF" />
    <alias alias="Database" type="Ecommerce_WCF.Database, Ecommerce_WCF" />
    <alias alias="DatabaseMock" type="Ecommerce_WCF.DatabaseMock, Ecommerce_WCF" />

    <container>
      <register type="IDatabase" mapTo="Database" />


      <!--<register type="IDatabase" mapTo="DatabaseMock" />-->
    </container>
  </unity>
```

Within the `container` tags, depending on which `register type` is commented/uncommented
it resolves the binding according the the real class or the mock which you can change
according to whether you're running/testing

Whenever a `Database` operation is used within my application I use the code:

```
var unity = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
            var proxy = unity.Resolve<IDatabase>();
            proxy.AddNewProduct(product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your question is not exactly clear, but something like below.

If you are referring to Unit Tests and not using any mock objects frameworks, something like this..

```
//production code/project
public interface IDatabase {
    void addNewProduct(Product product);
}

public class SystemUnderTest {
    private IDatabase _database;
    public SystemUnderTest(IDatabase database) {
        _database = database;
    }

    public void DoSomthing(Product product) {
        _database.addNewProduct(product);
    }
}

//Unit Test project
public class MockDatabase : IDatabase {
    public void addNewProduct(Product product)
    { //mock implementation}
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mock = new MockDatabase();
        var fakeProduct = new Product();
        mock.addNewProduct(fakeProduct );
        var sut = new SystemUnderTest(mock);

        //Act
        sut.DoSomthing(product);

        //Assert
        //Whatever you like to assert
    }
}
```

I use the constructor injection here, but you could also use property injection. It is harder to say exactly unless I have more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the call to the mock database only in a unit test project.  I would recommend not putting in an if statement for every service call to see if the call wants to use a live database or a mocked database.

Comment: Yes but how would I specify the service to use that particular database?

Comment: You can always move things to a configuration file.  Anything that might be environment specific.